Tengo un formulario y no devuelve mensaje de confirmación
Tengo un formulario y al rellenarlo y darle al botón de enviar me llega el correo pero no me llega a la pagina del formulario el mensaje de confirmación, en la url del navegador me aparece sendmail.php y el mensaje de confirmación
Este es el archivo formulario.html
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
   <div class="status"></div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
       <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-field" placeholder="Nombre" required>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
       <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
       <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" maxlength="10" class="input-field" placeholder="Teléfono">
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
       <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="input-field" placeholder="Asunto" required>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
       <textarea name="message" id="message" class="input-field" rows="8" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
       <div class="checkbox checkbox-top">
         <p class="white-text checkbox-top">
           <input id="check" type="checkbox" required >He leido y acepto la<a data-toggle="modal" class="preview white-text" href="#avisolegal">política de privacidad</a>
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
       <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default standard-button blue-button">Enviar mensaje</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>

Este es el archivo sendmail.php
<?php
    $from = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $sendTo = '<tu correo aqui>';
    $subject = 'MENSAJE DE LA PÁGINA WEB';
    $fecha = date("d-m-y");
    $hora = date("H:i");
    $fields = array('name' => 'Nombre', 'email' => 'Email', 'telephone' => 'Teléfono', 'subject' => 'Asunto', 'message' => 'Mensaje'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
    $okMessage = 'Se ha enviado el mensaje correctamente. Gracias, le contestaremos en breve.';
    $errorMessage = 'Ha habido un error. Vuelva a intentarlo mas tarde.';

    try
    {
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            
           $emailText = "Tienes un nuevo mensaje de la web enviado el $fecha a las $hora<br>=======================================================<br><br>";
            
           foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

               if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                   $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value<br>";
               }
           }
            
           $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
               'From: ' . $from,
               'Reply-To: ' . $from,
               'Return-Path: ' . $from,
           );

           mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

           $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        echo $encoded;
    }
    else {
        echo $responseArray['message'];
    }
?>    

Este es el archivo javascript
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            if (!e.preventDefault()) {
                var url = "sendmail.php";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                        var messageText = data.message;

                        var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                        if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                            $('#contact-form').find('.status').html(alertBox);
                            $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        })
    });


El mensaje de confirmación tendria que llegar a la pagina formulario.html en <div class="status"></div>

y como haces para que llegue a formulario.html  ... sinceramente no veo ninguna redireccion a ese archivo ...

Mediante el javascript

   var messageText = data.message;
   var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
 if (messageAlert && messageText) { $('#contact-form').find('.status').html(alertBox);```

eso deberia estar en el post ... no en los comentarios ...
